# Cannot overlay div if background color is transparent

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, vlc

I am having an interesting problem. I want to have a box with a border overlaid on top of a vlc web player. I can get it to work just fine if the background color is not transparent, but as soon as I set it to transparent, it gets drawn behind the player. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Here is a jsfiddle that shows what I am talking about (You need to have vlc web plugin installed in order for this to work. Additionally, you can only do overlays with firefox, for some reason).

http://jsfiddle.net/AsGuL/21/

Comment: Is it a flash powered player? If so then try setting wmode to opaque or transparent.

Comment: No, it's a vlc web player. While I don't even think it responds to wmode, I added it just in case. Regardless, it didn't make a difference =/.

Comment: perhaps the following link is of use: http://hacktohell.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-use-vlc-media-player-to-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but if someone with the same problem find it (like me), here is the solution :

VLC plugin have the attribute "windowless" you can use in this situation.
Just add `windowless="true"` in the embed tag.

From the documentation :

> **windowless**: (since VLC version 2.0.6) Draw the video on a window-less (non-accelerated) surface and allow styling (CSS overlay, 3D transformations, and much more). Default: false

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin